# Unit testing: allow for false-positive or bring duplication

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

I am testing a class that (apart from interacting with others) creates an object with fields made up of constants and values passed from caller:

```
private String createService(Long organizationId, String prototypeId,
    MedicalService medicalService)
{
    ServiceType service = new ServiceType();

    service.setClinic(organizationId.toString());
    service.setType("0");
    service.setPrototype(prototypeId);
    service.setCode(medicalService.getCode());
    service.setName(medicalService.getName());
    service.setIndependent(true);
    service.setRepeated(false);

    return remoteWS.createService(service);
}
```

Should I test that every field is set appropriately?

The reason I'm making doubt is that it would introduce duplication and decrease readability. Particularly I'm inclined to do reflection assert.

That would only allow to detect some "stupid" typing errors, e.g. writing `code` to `name` field if both are of type `String`.

Is this duplication reasonable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach this: if you have "data" that belongs "together" somehow, then that data is worth its **own** class.

And for such situations you would what scala calls a [value class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) for scala, or what kotlin provides as [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html). In other words: a container that only exists to wrap around a "set" of values.

The core aspect there: you provide reasonable implementation for a `equals()` method for example (when thinking Java terms). In other words: you enable a comparison like `dataObjectA.equals(dataObjectB)` which in turn compares **all** fields of that class.

And then you make use of that by creating such an instance of that data class within your unit test, carrying all expected values.

The question whether this is *worth* the effort is not something that other people can tell you. You have to assess A) chances of errors in that corner B) cost of such errors.

Coming from the TDD perspective, you *would* test even such details.

My personal thoughts: sometimes one has to be pragmatic. A unit test that just "records" what the production code is doing isn't too helpful in my eyes. Nonetheless, sometimes there is no other way than writing them down like this. In that sense: I would recommend to test these details, *but* I would step back and design a solution that makes writing the corresponding tests as simple and straight forward as possible.

In other words: I would test such things, but making sure that I can do that with minimal effort.

Comment: right, that's what i would do using reflection equals: create an expected instance with expected field values and compare to an actual object using Unitils for example. but i'm concerned more about the duplication: I would have a place to write almost the same code to test trivial (no logic) routine of setting values. and later i'd have to modify it in both places. makes sense anyway?